# How can I read JSON data from C++ through Java using a piqi definition

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers, thrift, protostuff

We use a 3rd party REST web service which defines their json API using piqi schemas.  Our current architecture needs this data to be read through a java client and transferred to a c++ binary.  Ideally, I would like all of the POJOs and c++ structs, as well as the data translation (json->java, java->c++) logic to be generated.  I've been investigating different combinations of protobuf, protostuff, and thrift, but there are still gaps in the flow.  Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Why not just send the JSON to C++?

Comment: That was my first thought also, but for reasons beyond my control, that is not an option.

This data also needs to be persisted and retrieved by a key. (no complex queries needed)  One option is just to use serialization and store it in a key/value store type db from java.

Answer (score 0):

Piqi author here. Most likely the third-party API provider exposes the JSON over HTTP API using [piqi-rpc](http://piqi.org/doc/piqi-rpc). Assuming you have the up-to-date `.piqi` definitions of the service there's a chance you can get output and/or send input data in Protocol Buffers format instead of JSON. Dealing with Protobuf in both Java and C++ is *a lot* easier and more reliable than dealing with JSON.

Unless the API provider explicitly disables use of Protocol Buffers as input/output format, you should be able to use this format by setting `Accept` header (and `Content-Type` for input parameters) to `application/x-protobuf` as described [here](http://piqi.org/doc/piqi-rpc/#codecontenttypecodeandcodeacceptcodeheaders). I would just try that and see if it works. If it doesn't you can ask the provider to turn it on.